# How to efficiently dispose resources in SWT?

Tags: java, swt

I have a simple SWT application which contains menus and controls. I have Text, tables, and trees available in the application, and I need to explicitly call the dispose method to clear the current object and give space for displaying other widgets on the screen. The system crashes when I call the dispose method if the widget is not already activated. Is there any better approach available to dispose an active widget to give room for another widget?

Comment: Are you really needing to dispose them or can you just add them to the parent container and remove them from the parent container?

Comment: I need to dispose them, only one widget should be active at a time.

Comment: What is your reason for disposing your widgets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you actually need to dispose of the widgets, you can keep a list of items you've added. Only dispose items you have added to the list.

So I would override JFrame with my main container class and have a method or two to add controls to the list. (If you need special control of where they go you can have an options class you pass in the add control method as well)

```
class MainContainer extends JFrame {
    private List<JComponent> currentComponents = new ArrayList<JComponent>();

    public void addControl(JComponent newComp) {
        // -- add it to the JFrame --
        ...

        // -- make a note that it is on --
        currentComponents.add(newComp);
    }

    public void removeControl(JComponent oldComp) {
        // -- check if it is in the list --
        if (currentComponents.contains(oldComp)) {
            // -- remove it from the JFrame --
            ...

            // -- remove it from the list --
            currentComponents.remove(oldComp);
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, all your components could be overriden and have a flag Displayed with

```
private boolean isDisplayed();
```

method and 
    private setDisplayed(boolean state);
such that when you do the add, you set the displayed state to true and when you do the remove, you only do it if the displayed state is true, and you set the state to false afterwards.